# Add a link from each privilege wiki to the main privileges page

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, privileges

It would be easier to navigate the privilege wikis if there was a link from each one the main privileges page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [main privileges page](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges) has nothing on it. There is no "there" there. The right hand sidebar is the same in all cases.